# Configuring partial word matching in AnswerWorks-Vantage Linguistics on ArcGIS Desktop and Server products?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-desktop, documentation

Esri, like many companies, has licensed iSEEK AnswerWorks from Vantage Linguistics for natural language search of the ArcGIS Help system. At ArcGIS 10, Esri dropped the Microsoft Keyword indexing search function from the Help system. Unfortunately, Esri's default settings for the indexed AnswerWorks searches are "full word match" only.

Has anyone figured out how the AnswerWorks settings in ArcGIS can be modified to return "partial word match" searches?

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be no other postings about AnswerWorks either here or at GeoNet, and so I think your best option will be to post an ArcGIS Idea to have the ArcGIS Help enhanced to support partial word searches.